# Coldfusion Ajax Can't pass email

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

I am using AJAX and coldfusion to submit the form. 
In the form I have a button that calls js function login(). This function is setting instance of coldfusion component, and calling the loginUser() method in cfc component.

Everything works fine when I pass firstname and lastname to loginUser function from javascript. loginUser(firstname,lastname) But the CF complains whenever I am trying to pass  an actual email address to a form.  So to make it simple, 
loginUser("one","two","three") will work but
loginUser("one","two", "three@") will not work and CF will display message:

Error invoking CFC /ATCdev/JanuszChudzynski/MobileWeb/ajax.cfc : Not Found [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your URL parameters to see more information]

So I have two questions.

1 How can I make it work?

2 How can I add a CFDebug if I am using

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="ajax" jsclassname="proxy" />
```

to set a cfc proxy.

thanks in advance!

I am pasting code below:

cfc

```
<cffunction name="loginUser" access = "remote" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="firstname" type="string" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="lastname" type="string" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="useremail" type="any" required="true" default=""/>
        <cfargument name="license" type="string" required="false" />
        <cfargument name="workshopid" type="string" required="false" />

        <cfreturn "#firstname##lastname##useremail#">

    </cffunction>
```

JS

```
function validatelogin(){
        var check = $("#loginForm").valid();
        console.log("check "+check);
        if(check)
        {
            login();    
        }
    }

    function login(){
        var instance = new proxy();
        instance.setCallbackHandler(loginCallback);
        var id = $("input[name='workshop']:checked").val();

        var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
        var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var licensenumber = $("#licensenumber").val();
        console.log(id + " " + firstname + " " + lastname + " " + email + " " + licensenumber);

        if(id&&firstname&&lastname&&email&&licensenumber){
            //instance.loginUser(firstname,lastname,email,licensenumber,id);
            console.log(" Email:  "+email);
            instance.loginUser(firstname,lastname,"jchudzynski@");

//          instance.loginU();
        }
        else{
            console.log("Javascript Error. Not all fields are valid."); 
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
    <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="loginform.cfm">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Select your workshop from options below </legend>
    <input type="radio" name="workshop" id="workshop1" class="custom" data-mini="true" value="workshop1" checked/>
    <label for="workshop1">Workshop 1.</label>

    <input type="radio" name="workshop" id="workshop2" class="custom" data-mini="true" value="workshop2"/>
    <label for="workshop2">Workshop 2.</label>

    </fieldset>


<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="firstname" >First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name" data-mini="true" class="required" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="lastname" >Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last Name" data-mini="true" class="required" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="email" >Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="email" data-mini="true" class="required email" />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="licensenumber" >License Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="licensenumber" id="licensenumber" value="" placeholder="License Number" data-mini="true" class="required" />
</div>

<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="validatelogin()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: To isolate the problem, what happens when you try to run the function with either cfinvoke or createObject?

Comment: hi, I used CFInvoke and it appears to run fine.
It doesn't report any errors when I pass email

<cfinvoke component="ajax" method="loginUser" firstname = "j" lastname = "b" useremail="jchudz@uwf.edu" returnvariable="debugging" >
<cfoutput>#debugging#</cfoutput>

Comment: u can try invoking directly in browser with url `http://localhost/foo.cfc?method=loginUser&firstname=x&lastname=l&email=jchudzynski%40&cfdebug` and also use firebug/chrome console to compare that to what's sent by cfajaxproxy